# Django channels: Alternative of Redis for windows machine?

Tags: python, django, windows, redis, django-channels

As per documentation of redis,

> **A.3.1 Drawbacks of Redis on Windows**
>
> Windows doesn’t support the fork system call, which Redis uses in a
>   variety of situations to dump its database to disk. Without the
>   ability to fork, Redis is unable to perform some of its necessary
>   database-saving methods without blocking clients until the dump has
>   completed.

*Questions:*

1) If I'm not wrong, this issue will occur when concurrent users increases? Is that correct?

2) Is it really an issue, if we deploy channels on a windows machine (production server)? If yes, is there any better alternative of redis?

3) How to test the above-mentioned drawback on a production server?

**Note:**

Can't use wsl2(as officially not released) or wsl as the current windows server won't support.

Comment: If you don't need data persistence for your Redis instance, there's no problem.

Comment: @AKX I need data persistence, as I'm sending message to channel group(only one group) for every 5 seconds. And users are getting added to channel group which I'm considering as concurrent users. Is there any better approach for windows machine?

Comment: Persistence as in "if the Redis server shuts down, the old data is still there" in this case.

Comment: if you are running windows server are you able to run a linux VM? (even if its just for redis)

How many concurrent connections are you expecting django-channels to be handling, (pythons default limit of file descriptors on windows is very low when it comes to open connections). We have found that (without recompiling python) we cant maintain over 500 open connection on windows, on linux (or any other *nix system) there seems to just follow the system limit.

Comment: I would also flag async python (and channels is falls into this bucket) is much less solid on windows.

Comment: @AKX So this, is not my use case. As my application won't bother about old data. So, this drawback won't effect or it does in any special case?

Comment: @MatthausWoolard No, I have tried to install docker using toolbox from [here](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/releases), but it doesn't help. So, installing VM is also not possible on this `windows server 2008 r2`, though there are some workarounds which doesn't helped me. And my consumers are `async`. Do I need to change to `sync`?

Comment: @Pythoncoder changing your code to sync will not change how channels works under the hood. So you will have the same issue. Most notably the limited number of open connections that python can handle. In addition you are strongly suggested to put channels behind a revers proxy (like nginx) so you need to find one of these on windows that can handle many 100s of open connections.

Answer (score 2):

as far as I know to come over this issue you may try one of these options:

- setup redis on a docker container using [this image](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/) and use it in your project.
- install linux using a virtualbox and setup redis there.

In both of them since you are running redis in linux environment I don't think you get a problem but like I said try them before going to production. :)

For testing purpose maybe a simulation would work fine first write a test with lots of read and write and try it on both redis on windows and redis on docker and measure the benchmarks.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Before that, I want to confirm, what is actual issue we will face with that drawback? Is it number of concurrent users? Or, If possible, can you please suggest/provide any link, how to test that drawback?

Comment: According to what they say redis blocks clients when it want's to save data, It works like a sleep() in code when redis tries to dump data until it finishes. For testing purpose maybe a simulation would work fine first write a test with lots of read and write and try it on both redis on windows and redis on docker. I will edit the answer with testing process.

Answer (score 0):

[Memurai](https://memurai.com) is a good Redis for Windows alternative. Memurai is based on Redis source code.